# Using DBFlow, how to encrypt an already existing database?

Tags: android, database, sqlcipher, dbflow

I'm using DBFlow to handle databases in my project and I want to make the existing database encrypted.

I know that I probably will have to drop the existing unencrypted database and create another encrypted. And I also know that I can use SQLCipher with DBFlow as described [the documentation](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage/SQLCipherSupport.md).

My question is: how and when should I drop the database and how do I recreate one without requesting that the users uninstall the app? Can it be done via migrations?

Please provide some code on how to achieve that. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? I have a similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Another probable solution I can think of is to use encryption at hardware layer for mobile memory encryption.

http://itstillworks.com/encrypted-memory-card-3090.html

http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/VS930/JB/Userguide/basics_memory_encryption.html